# How to handle "switch/case" when new parameters added in SW release

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

How to handle when there is a new SW Release sometime and it adds another index to `switch case`. Index represents a parameter in this case. For example,

Rel1: i = 1-5, 7 (excluding 6)

Rel2: i = 1-7

```
for (int i = 1; i<=7;i++)
{
  switch (i)
  {
    case 1: /*process data*/ break;
    case 2: /*process data*/ break;
    case 3: /*process data*/ break;
    case 4: /*process data*/ break;
    case 5: /*process data*/ break;
    // case 6: // REL 2
    case 7: /*process data*/ break;
    default: break;
  }
}
```

Can I actually check by adding `if` statement between those cases? Any better idea?

Comment: Do you want to tell your application at runtime which release to handle or at compile time?

Comment: Why don't you put `if (Rel2) {...}` right after `case 6:` ?

Comment: Someone re-phase my question and description, I am really appreciate for that. That is perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define` which release is this and then use `#ifdef`.

```
  switch (i)
  {
    case 1: /*process data*/ break;
    case 2: /*process data*/ break;
    case 3: /*process data*/ break;
    case 4: /*process data*/ break;
    case 5: /*process data*/ break;
#ifdef REL_2
    case 6: /*process data*/ break;  // <-- executed only for REL_2
#endif
    case 7: /*process data*/ break;
    default: break;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that is why I ask in the main thread, can I actually put if else between cases. Thanks. Thank you all for the answers.  Some of your ideas are high level which I could not get the whole picture. I apologized for that.

Answer (score 1):

In production code if I have an unexpected result like this I often try to capture and log it.
Throwing an exception *may* be ok depending on how it's handled.  For future-proofing it's usually good to design stuff like this to gracefully handle new values.

Comment: For now, it is not a good design. This tool process and analyze the offline data, it depends on other configurations, so it unpredictable.  it is hard to handle those new parameters. I thought there is a way for work-around for time being. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a 'for' loop, use a 'while' loop with a release number generator function.

Pseudo code:

```
typedef enum {rel1, rel2} rel_t;

// Where 'ReleaseSequence' is a generator functor. Class that takes rel_t
// in constructor and creates an appropriate functor that returns the
// required sequence of numbers for a particular release

ReleaseSequence seq(rel1);
while (i = seq()) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1:...
        case 2:...
        case 3:...
        case 4:...
        case 5:...
        case 6:...
        case 7:...
        default:
               break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see your potential ideas here, the main sequence is about 100+, if rel1 only add one index, i have to get another set of sequence for rel1, e.g. 1-7 or 100-101. I might not get your whole ideas. I thought I can do like if (REL1) add one more index. Or set a flag. Thanks for your times.

Answer (score 0):

I find it very strange to see a `switch` nested within a loop...

It looks like you are executing a pipe. Then why don't you simply define is as one.

For example, a simple array of pointer to functions would do nicely. You can define one such pipe per release, and provide "noop" functions for the parameters to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch unexpected values, shouldn't you put that check in the `default` part?

```
...
default:
    assert(false);   // We should never get here!
```